# Superimpose a line on a histogram in Gnuplot

Tags: c++, gnuplot

I use C++ in Xcode on Mac and a pipe method to communicate with Gnuplot. I am interested in converting my arrays into graphs directly through the program, after I run it. Using

```
FILE *f = popen("gnuplot -persist", "w");
```

I open the file and then communicate using fprintf.

Now, I have some data in arrays of interest. `w` is a "proposed" array of standard normal variables and I intend to check if it is indeed a Gaussian distribution with mean = 0 and variance = 1 .To do that I plot a histogram. After that I want to superimpose a real Gaussian function, which has `ex` as a x coordinate values and `gauss` as y coordinate values directly on the histogram. How can I do that?

Here's the code so far:

```
double start = -4; //min
double end = 4 ; //max
double numberofbins = 100;
double width = (end-start)/numberofbins ;

fprintf (f,
         "set ylabel '# of elements'\n"
         "set xlabel 'The numbers'\n"
         "Min = %g\n" //where binning starts
         "Max = %g\n" // where binning ends
         "n = %g\n" // the number of bins
         "width = 10**(-1)\n" // binwidth;  (Max-Min)/n
         "bin(x) = width*(floor((x-Min)/width)+0.5) + Min\n"
         "f(x)= e**((-x**2)/2) / sqrt(2*pi)\n"
         "plot '-' using (bin($1)):(1) smooth freq with boxes,'' u $2:$3 with lines linestyle 1\n",start,end,numberofbins)

for (int i= 0; i < numberofpoints; i++){
    fprintf(f, "%g %g %g\n", w[i], ex[i], gauss[i]);
}

fclose(f);
```

Here is the result if I run the demonstrated code:

[image: output 01]

As we can see, the binning was successful but the line was omitted and gives the following error:

```
gnuplot> plot '-' using (bin($1)):(1) smooth freq with boxes,'' u $2:$3 with lines linestyle 1
                                                               ^
     line 100000: column() called from invalid context
```

I have checked online but nobody is practicing communicating with Gnuplot that way.

If I plot only the 2:3 part (without binning), I get this graph:

[image: output 02]

Thus, the problem might be with the compatibility of these two plots.

Comment: either use `...'' u 2:3 with lines...` or `...'' u ($2):($3) with lines...`

Comment: @theozh Now it gives this error: `line 100000: warning: Skipping data file with no valid points`

Comment: using `plot '-' using ...` the data has to directly follow the plot command and to be finished with `e`. I don't think this is the case with your data.

Comment: @theozh I do not understand your last comment, could you please elaborate more on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there are different ways to plot "inline" data

```
plot '-' u 1:2 w lines
1 11
2 22
3 33
e
```

From gnuplot `help special-filenames`

> If you use both '-' and '' on the same plot command, you'll need to
>   have two sets of inline data, ...

This means:

```
plot '-' u 1:2 w boxes, '' u 1:2 w lines
1 11
2 22
3 33
e
1 11
2 22
3 33
e
```

So, instead, I would generate a datablock in the beginning of your generated command string and reuse the data as many times as you need it during your plotting command.

```
$Data <<EOD
1 11
2 22
3 33
EOD

plot $Data u 1:2 w boxes, '' u 1:2 w lines
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but this is not the case. I need to superpose a *theoretical* Gaussian line on the histogram. As you see, the histogram's height is 4000 and the line's height is 0.4.

Comment: then normalize both to 1 or scale the one or the other. For example: `plot $Data u 1:2 w boxes, '' u 1:($3/0.4*4000) w lines` or something like that.

Comment: I have solved the problem by creating a second axis and plotting it according to it. Thanks for the help, I really did not know about the "e" business!

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem by creating a second y axis on the same graph and plotting according to it. The code used was:

```
 fprintf (f,
             "set xlabel 'The numbers'\n"
             "Min = %g\n" //where binning starts
             "Max = %g\n" // where binning ends
             "n = %g\n" // the number of bins
             "width = 10**(-1)\n" // binwidth;  (Max-Min)/n
             "bin(x) = width*(floor((x-Min)/width)+0.5) + Min\n"
             "set ytics 100 nomirror tc lt 1\n"
             "set ylabel '# of elements' tc lt 1\n"
             "set y2tics 0.4 nomirror tc lt 2\n"
             "set y2label 'Theoretical Gaussian' tc lt 2\n"
             "plot '-' using (bin($1)):(1) smooth freq with boxes title 'Generator Histogram','-' u 1:2 with l axes x1y2 title 'Theoretical Gaussian (mean=0, std = 1)'\n",start,end,numberofbins) ;

    for (int i= 0; i < numberofpoints; i++){
        fprintf(f, "%g\n", w[i]);
    } 
    fprintf(f,"e\n");

    for (int i= 0; i < numberofpoints; i++){
        fprintf(f, "%g %g\n",ex[i], gauss[i]);
    }
    fprintf(f,"e\n");
    fclose(f);
```

which plots this:
[image]